# Dispatch group won't block after JSON call

Tags: swift, uitableview, grand-central-dispatch, alamofire

I'm trying to get my JSON call to return before I populate the TableCell, however as a newbie to swift I can't make the call block using dispatch queues....can anyone please advise how I make it halt at `group.wait()` line in the code posted below.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let queue:DispatchQueue = DispatchQueue.global()
    let group:DispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

    Alamofire.request("http://localhost:3000/locations.json").responseJSON { response in
        group.enter()
        //print(response.request)  // original URL request
        //print(response.response) // HTTP URL response
        //print(response.data)     // server data
        //print(response.result)   // result of response serialization
        guard response.result.error == nil else{
            print("Error: unable to get a list of locations.")
            return
        }
        if let JSON = response.result.value {
            //  print("JSON: \(JSON)")
            if let result = response.result.value as? [[String: Any]] {
                nameArray = result.map { ($0["name"] as? String)! }
                print(nameArray[0])

            }
        }
        group.leave()
    }

    group.notify(queue: queue) {
        // This closure will be executed when all tasks are complete
        print("All tasks complete")
    }

    // synchronize on task completion by waiting on the group to block the current thread.
    print("block while waiting on task completion")
    let _ = group.wait()
    print("continue")

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Picture", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = LocationData[indexPath.row].name
    print (LocationData[indexPath.row].name)
    print(indexPath.row)
    // cell.textLabel?.text = nameArray[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Detail") as? DetailViewController {
        vc.selectedImage = pictures[indexPath.row]
        navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: You are strongly discouraged from blocking `cellForRowAt` because you will get a terrible use experience. Load the JSON in viewDidLoad **asynchronously** and then reload the table view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call `group.enter()` *before* you perform your request, not inside the closure.

---

But because Alamofire uses the main queue for its completion handlers, if you `wait` on the main queue until the completion handler calls `leave()`, you'll deadlock. If you really wanted to use this "wait" pattern, you'd have to specify that `request` should use that background queue for its completion handlers.

---

Having said that, while it's so intuitively appealing to `wait`, this is not an appropriate usage of it. (Nor would the other logically equivalent solution, using semaphores.)

You should initiate your network request and then asynchronously update the cell. But `cellForRowAtIndexPath` should not be waiting for network requests.

---

I was going to suggest alternative implementation, but it's not entirely clear what you're trying to do (right now, you're doing another network request for every row of the table, which doesn't seem right). Where does `LocationData` come from? Assuming you really wanted to do one request to get the names of the locations, you'd move that request to `viewDidLoad` and then call `tableView.reload()` in the completion handler.

```
var locations: [String]?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    Alamofire.request("http://localhost:3000/locations.json").responseJSON { response in
        guard response.result.error == nil else{
            print("Error: unable to get a list of locations.")
            return
        }
        if let result = response.result.value as? [[String: Any]] {
            self.locations = result.map { $0["name"] as! String }
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return locations?.count ?? 0
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Picture", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = locations?[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Rob, you're a genius - thank you so much, I've been working on this since Friday (I've probably spent 15 hours trying to figure it out). I've still got a lot to learn about Swift and to be honest it's a bit like walking over a cliff after coming from a Ruby on Rails background......

Comment: Also, don't feel bad about taking a while to get used to Swift's asynchronous patterns. It will probably feel like second nature once you do it a few times and get accustomed to these patterns.